# Why don't these gitignore entries work?

Tags: git, gitignore

This is my folder struction:

- Root

  - ProgramName

    - bin

      - Debug

        - Backups

          - Backup (This folder contains various text files)

I want to ignore the Backups folder and all of it's files, subfolders, and files in those subfolders.

I don't want to use `Backups/` because if I understand correctly that would match all folders anywhere under the Root directory named Backups.

Right now I have: `Debug/Backup` in my exclude file, but that's not working.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue of how you are managing your files and builds. For example, your directory structure gives me the impression that you are trying to store compiled binaries in git. if it was me, anything in bin would be exempt from being stored in the repo. Also anything called Backups would be either outside the project or removed as repos are very good at restoring.

Comment: I agree with Derek actually. Default ignores for Visual Studio projects includes `bin/` and `obj/` thus effectively ignoring build artifacts.

Comment: I agree with the other guys. That said, if you want to put this in your root .gitignore you could try prefixing your rule with an asterisk: `*/Debug/Backups`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have .gitignore at any level in hierarchy, rules for concrete directory get gathered from it and all of its parents. So you could place .gitignore with `Backups/` in Debug folder.

Also you could specify path in root .gitignore that starts with `/`, thus matching only your concrete path. So in your case it is `/ProgramName/bin/Debug/Backups/`
If ignore pattern finishes with trailing `/` - it will match directories only.